# JQM removes my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Having a very small example demonstrating my issue with jquerymobile:

```
JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/forrest_gump/Q73Mk/3/
```

As you can see i call jqm changePage() and it appears for a second but the it is suddenly removed by #pageIndex

I spent a lot of time trying to find out why!?! Am I stupid or is it a jqm bug?

Comment: What should exactly happen here??

Comment: As I understand after using changePage JQM should change active page from #pageIndex to #pageLogin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `pageinit` fires when page is ready to be shown but still hidden, as there is sequence of *events* that still not occurred on that page. Changing page doesn't stop those *events* from occuring, resulting in showing the target page for a while and reverting back to previous page.

You have two solutions for this:

- **Solution one:**

  Delay `changePage` using `setTimeout()` to ensure that all *page events* are triggered.

  ```
  $(document).on('pagecreate', '#pageIndex', function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#pageLogin", {
              transition: "slideup"
          });
      }, 100); /* 100ms or more */
  });
  ```

  **Note:** `pageinit` is deprecated and replaced with `pagecreate`. Also, `$.mobile.changePage` is replaced with `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page", { options });`.

  > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LZBLA/)**

---

- **Solution two:**

  Listen to `pagebeforechange` event to decide which page to show first.

  ```
  $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, ui) {
      if (ui.toPage[0].id == "pageIndex" && typeof ui.options.fromPage === "undefined") {
          $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#pageLogin", {
              transition: "slideup"
          });
          e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
  ```

  > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yk9mf/)**

Comment: If I understand you correctly then pageshow event should help (because the page is already shown), but it doenst!
Also I don`t understand why you use such if conditions in the second solution. In this case pageIndex will never load, right?

Comment: @DmitryIsakov it won't help because there's another event after `pageshow` which is `pagechange`.

Comment: I tried pagechange event also but it doesnt work too.

Comment: @DmitryIsakov last page event is `pagecontainertransition` but this **cant** be bound on `#pageID`. check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KPtBT/

Comment: Also I don`t understand why you use such if conditions in the second solution. In this case pageIndex will never load, right?

Comment: @DmitryIsakov because _page events_ are deprecated and replaced with `pagecontainer` events. Those new events cant be _bound_ to specific page, thus you need to use `if statement` or `switch` in order to execute specific code on a specific _page_. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865

Comment: I cannot comment about jqm 1.4.2 (I just used it for this sample) but on 1.3.2 that I got used to (where changePage is not deprecated) it has the same behavior. And if I understand correctly I can bind handlers to specific pages like I do here: http://jsfiddle.net/forrest_gump/Q73Mk/8/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48870/discussion-between-omar-and-dmitry-isakov)