# jquery mobile Index page shows and then flips to account-login?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an index page which calls the security script to see if you are logged in. This is set in a pagebeforeshow event

```
 $(document).off('pagebeforeshow', '#index')
            .on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function() {
                var pagetag = "index";

                window.localStorage.setItem("keytag", pagetag);
                init();

        });
```

as this code is running and then executes that the user is not logged in. It flashes the content of the index page for a second and then proceeds to the login page. 
Which event is best to run before the page is ever created to first check logged in so i dont get a flash of the index.html

my init() part for clarity

```
function security(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://m.mysite.com/ajaxResponder.php?method=security",
        dataType: 'html',
        complete: function(data){
            if(data.responseText == 'logout'){
           $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', 'account-login.html', {
                                                               transition: 'none',
                                                               changeHash: false,
                                                               reverse: true,
                                                               showLoadMsg: false
                                                               });
           }else {
             //stay on index page
           }... continued script etc
```

**Answer to anyone else who is after this.** (thanks to Omar for the heads up)

I added

```
data-needs-auth="true"
```

to page div.

and i added this code

```
  $(document).on('pagebeforechange', function (event,data) {
              if (data.toPage[0].id == "index" && data.toPage.attr('data-needs-auth') == 'true'){
                    if (!window.localStorage.getItem("login")) {
                       $.mobile.changePage("account-login.html", { changeHash: false });
                       event.preventDefault();

                       }
                }

     });
```

Comment: `pagebeforechange` is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141500/jqm-removes-my-page/22143490#22143490

Comment: Been searching for ages, couldn't find the correct way of describing it. lol many thanks Omar

Comment: Added answer to any one who needs this also